# Clarification on metric preserving embedding of unit sphere $S^2$

Tags: differential-topology, self-learning, isometry

I am trying to understand [this answer on an isometric embedding of a sphere (with its geodesic distance) to an euclidean space cannot exist  and Nash embedding theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/87509/471078).

The statement of Nash's theorem is somewhat straightforward to follow which says - "every Riemannian manifold can be isometrically embedded as a submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$". Also, I am able to understand that the metric on $S^2$ is the induced metric from $\Bbb R^{3}$.

However, I am unable to follow these statements - "In that case, the identity map is a *locally* metric-preserving embedding into $\mathbb R^2$, but it doesn't preserve the *global* distance. .... Thus, the natural embedding works as an isometry when we view the two spaces as *Riemannian manifolds*, but not when we consider them directly as *metric spaces*. "

Can you please clarify the following: What is the identity map being referred here? How is it only locally isometric but not globally? What is the natural embedding?

P.S. - I am a beginner in this field and surely, not familiar with much of the advanced concepts. Requesting to help me in understand in an intuitive manner if possible.

Comment: Borsuk-Ulam tells us that, given any continuous map $f \colon S^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$, there is a point $x\in S^2$ such that $f(x)=f(-x)$. Whatever the distance between $x$ and $-x$ is, that goes to $0$ after applying $f$.

Comment: @NelliKuukeri: But is that the identity map being referred here?

Comment: Where is this "here"?

Comment: @NelliKuukeri: In the question - "In that case, the identity map is a locally metric-preserving embedding into R2, but it doesn't preserve the global distance". I am specifically confused about the details of the identity map  - meaning its domain, codomain, and exact functional form.

Comment: The linked answer, while highly upvoted, is non-rigorous. I suggest, you just ignore it. The correct statement requires you to understand what a Riemannian metric is and the notion of  a Riemannian isometry. This would be discussed in any serious Riemannian Geometry textbook.