# Isometric embedding of $(\mathbb{R}^2, d_\infty)$ into $(\mathbb{R}^m,d_2)$?

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose we consider $M = (\mathbb{R}^2, d_\infty)$ (here to be clear $d_\infty$ refers to the "maximum metric"). Bounds relating $d_\infty$ to $d_2$ show that this space is homeomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}^2, d_2)$ so $M$ is in some sense "a surface".

Can we find a distance-preserving map $f:M\to\mathbb{R}^m$? I think this proves no: $(0,0), (0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$ are four points mutually unit-distance from each other in $M$ and so would need to map, under $f$, to a regular tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^m$ but the lines connecting these points cross (look at the diagonals of this "square tetrahedron") which doesn't happen for any tetrahedra in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Thus I think this proves that there is no distance-preserving map from $M$ to any subset of $R^m$ for $m \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

**My first question is: does this proof work? If it doesn't, can we find a different proof of this fact?**

My second question is: I have heard in the statement of such things as the [Nash embedding theorems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorems) and [as discussed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87503/isometric-embedding), there is a different notion of "isometric embedding" that comes from Riemannian geometry that essentially preserves the lengths of curves in $(\mathbb{R}^2, d_\infty)$ but does not necessarily imply global preservation of the metric. **Is there such an isometric embedding from $M$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$? If so, can we describe it?**

I understand that this second question requires reinterpreting $M$ as a Riemannian manifold rather than a metric space or something similar but I do not currently have the technical knowledge to read literature to answer or even phrase this question properly, hence me asking on MSE.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something, but doesn't $f(x, y) = (x, y, 0, \ldots, 0)$ do the trick (provided $m \geq 2$)? Why is this obvious embedding not isometric?

Comment: @Joppy perhaps I am wrong, but say $m=2$ and notice that $d((0,1),(1,0)) = \sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean distance whereas $d((0,1),(1,0))=1$ with the maximum distance. Thus your map doesn't work.

Comment: @IskyMathews In the title you have it wrong it should be $\mathbb{R}^m$ with the euclidean metric

Comment: @aldodecristo: You are correct! That was a very major typo! it made the question completely trivial.

Comment: Ah yes if one has the max-norm and the other has the 2-norm then there should be no isometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, as you say, no isometry from the plane with the uniform metric into a Euclidean space. I'm not entirely convinced the crossing diagonals are a problem, but here's an alternative proof: In the uniform metric the distance along one edge of the unit square agrees with the Euclidean distance on a number line, so the isometric image of each side of the square is a Euclidean segment. On the other hand, the uniform distance between *every* pair of boundary points on opposite edges of the unit square is unity, while no two Euclidean segments have this property. (Even more, there is no point in a Euclidean space lying at the same distance from every point of a Euclidean segment.)

As to your second question, the Nash embedding theorem is about Riemannian manifolds, and the plane with the uniform metric is not a Riemannian manifold, i.e., the uniform metric is not induced by a Riemannian metric.

Comment: I'm fairly sure your comment about sending segments to Euclidean segments also formalises the argument about crossing diagonals, as it shows the unit square and the diagonals must be sent to a regular tetrahedron as described with these segments as its edges. However, they cross and this cannot happen in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Regardless, great answer. I'll be writing one of my own about Q1 as I forgot that I had another more water-tight proof for that that I think is of some interest to others and then I'll accept yours.

Comment: Agreed about the crossing edges: I didn't think the argument was wrong, only that there seem to be details to fill in. (Generally, the simpler the "impossible" configuration, the easier to prove non-existence. :)